# How to detect and block non-browser API requests in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, api

How would I be able to identify whether a JSON request is coming from a browser or a server? I'm developing an AJAX application where I need to block all non-browser API requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to really block the requests without Authentication / Authorization mechanisms but using only HTTP specification.
However, you can use the HTTP Header's User-Agent field

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

And trace / filter all the requests using that field value.
I would implement it by writing the custom ActionFilter and applying it to the Controller.

Are you going to block the requests for security purpose?

Comment: I just want to be able to reduce the amount of spam traffic that may come from server-side HTTP requests. Obviously, it's easy to see JSON post parameters and URL in JavaScript, so I need to have a mechanism where the server can identify whether the request is coming from a browser or not.

Comment: The problem is that there is no 100% guarantee mechanism for that purpose. It's pretty easy to tweak the User-Agent information and emulate the browser behavior when making a web request. This is a nature of the HTTP protocol. I think, you need to use a bit different approaches such as maintaining spammers IP address database, proper moderation and blocking users, etc. In the advanced cases, I would recommend training the Spam Classifiers using one of the Machine Learning algorithms - but it will require some effort.